# How to solve this maximization problem | KKT conditions

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Maximize the objective function $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (1-e^{-k_ix_i})$, where $(k_i >0) \in \mathbb{R}, (0\leq x_i \leq 1) \in \mathbb{R} $ .

$\max\sum_{i=1}^n (1-e^{-k_ix_i})$

Subject to

i) $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(1-x_i) \leq A$

ii) $x_i \geq 0$, $\forall i=1\cdots n$

I have followed some examples given in Internet and have tried to solve.

My attempt :

$L({x}, {\mu}) = (1-e^{-k_ix_i}) - \mu_0\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}x_i(1-x_i) - A\right) - \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \mu_i(-x_i)$

$\nabla_{x_i}L({x}, {\mu}) = k_ie^{-k_ix_i} +\mu_0 (2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n)+\mu_i= 0$

$\mu_0 = - \frac{k_ie^{-k_ix_i}}{2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n}$

Is my approach correct? For some values $\mu_0 > 0$ and for some values $\mu_0 <0$ .

How to find i) $\mu_0,\mu_i$ ii) $x_i$ iii) and final set of equations.

---

Comment: Is it $\cdots + \mu_0 (2x_i - 1)$?